# C: Losing strings when exiting functions

Tags: c, string, function, unix

I'm trying to implement a basic shell, I have several functions within it that deal with strings, trying to find file names, implement something equivalent to `*argv[]` and so on.

I have strings in `main()`, which are passed to a function to be populated. Next the program returns to `main()`, which passes the strings to another function to be acted upon.

I was debugging with `lldb` and found that I was successfully populating the strings with the correct values in the first function but upon exiting the function, re-entering `main()` the `output_str` string was `NULL` again. I thought strings, since they point to space in memory would retain values. They seem to for all but one case, when flag = 1 in the code below.

I can't figure out what's happening as the values seem to only be lost after the final `}` of the function.

Edited to add complete code, hope it isn't too large.

The code works with say, `cat input.txt` but not with `cat input.txt>output.txt` when I try to redirect the output from `stdout` to a file
Thank you for your help in advance.

Here is the function .c file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <signal.h>

void sig_handler(int signo)
{
        if (signo == SIGINT)
        {
                fprintf(stdout, "\n");
                fflush(stdout);
        }
}
int check_redirect(char *line, int flag)
{
        int n = 0;
        if (line == NULL) return (flag);
        else
        {
                do
                {
                        if (line[n] == '>') flag = 1;
                        n++;
                }while (line[n] != '\0');
        }

        return (flag);
}

void string_breakdown(char *line, char **output_str, int count, char* temp, char *filename, int *f, int *saved_stdout, int flag, int debug)
{
        char *sep = " \n";
        char *delim = ">\n";

        if (line != NULL)
        {
                temp = strtok(line, delim);
                while (temp != NULL)
                {
                        output_str[count] = temp;

                        if (debug) fprintf(stderr, "1:%s\n2:%s\n3:%s\n", line, temp, output_str[count]);

                        count++;
                        output_str = realloc (output_str, (count + 1) * sizeof (char *) );

                        temp = strtok(NULL, delim);
                }
                if (flag)
                {
                        count = 0;
                        strcpy(filename, output_str[1]);
                        output_str[1] = NULL;

                        *saved_stdout = dup(1);

                        *f = open(filename , O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666);

                        dup2(*f, 1);

                        temp = strtok(*output_str[0], sep);
                        while (temp != NULL)
                        {
                                output_str[count] = temp;

                                //if (debug) fprintf(stderr, "1:%s\n2:%s\n3:%s\n", line, temp, output_str[count]);

                                count++;
                                output_str = realloc (output_str, (count + 1) * sizeof (char *));

                                temp = strtok(NULL, sep);
                        }
                }

                else
                {
                        count = 0;
                        temp = strtok(line, sep);
                        while (temp != NULL)
                        {
                                output_str[count] = temp;

                                if (debug) fprintf(stderr, "1:%s\n2:%s\n3:%s\n", line, temp, output_str[count]);

                                count++;
                                output_str = realloc (output_str, (count + 1) * sizeof (char *));

                                temp = strtok(NULL, sep);
                        }
                }
        }
}

void com_exec(char *line, char **output_str, char *filename, int *f, int *saved_stdout, int flag, int debug)
{
        char *command = malloc(sizeof(char *));
        command = output_str[0];
        char *name = "HOME";
        int ret_val = 0;
        pid_t child_pid;
        int child_status;
        if (command == NULL);
        else if (strcmp("cd", command) == 0)
        {
                if (output_str[1] == NULL) output_str[1] = getenv(name);

                ret_val = 0;
                ret_val = chdir(output_str[1]);
                if (ret_val) perror(NULL);
        }

        else
        {
                child_pid = fork ();
                if (child_pid == 0)
                {
                        if (debug)
                        {
                                system(line);
                                fprintf(stderr, "Post System Pre Exec\n1:%s\n2:%s\n3:%s\n", line, output_str[0], command);
                                sleep(2);
                        }

                        execvp(command, output_str);

                        if (flag)
                        {
                                close(*f);

                                dup2(*saved_stdout, 1);
                                close(*saved_stdout);

                        }

                        fprintf (stdout, "Unknown command\n");
                        exit (0);
                }

                else
                {
                        if (flag)
                        {
                                close(*f);

                                dup2(*saved_stdout, 1);
                                close(*saved_stdout);
                        }

                        signal(SIGINT, sig_handler);

                        usleep(500000);

                        //Parent process waits for child to finish
                        if (debug) fprintf (stderr, "parent waiting\n");

                        wait(&child_status);
                        waitpid(child_pid, &child_status, 0);

                        signal(SIGINT, SIG_DFL);
                }
        }
```

Here is the functions .h file:

```
#ifndef SHELL_H_INCLUDED
#define SHELL_H_INCLUDED

void sig_handler(int signo);

int prompt(char *line, size_t len, ssize_t read);

int check_redirect(char *line, int flag);

void string_breakdown(char *line, char **output_str, int count, char* temp, char *filename, int *f, int *saved_stdout, int flag, int debug);

void com_exec(char *line, char **output_str, char *filename, int *f, int *saved_stdout, int flag, int debug);

#endif // LINKLAYER_H_INCLUDED
```

Below is main.c, where the function is called.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <signal.h>

#include "shell.h"

int main(void)
{
        int debug = 0;

        char *line = NULL;
        size_t len = 0;
        ssize_t read = 0;

        int flag = 0;

        int f = 0;
        int saved_stdout = 0;

        do
        {
                flag = 0;

                //read = prompt(line, len, read);
                char buffer[15];
                time_t now = time(NULL);
                strftime(buffer, 15, "[%d/%m %H:%M]", localtime(&now) );

                fprintf(stdout, "%s # ", buffer);

                signal(SIGINT, SIG_IGN);
                read = getline (&line, &len, stdin);
                signal(SIGINT, SIG_DFL);

                flag = check_redirect(line, flag);

                char **output_str = malloc(sizeof(char *));
                int count = 0;
                char* temp = NULL;
                char *filename = malloc(sizeof(char *));

                string_breakdown(line, output_str, count, temp, filename, &f, &saved_stdout, flag, debug); // function call of problem function

                com_exec(line, output_str, filename, &f, &saved_stdout, flag, debug);
        } while (read != EOF);

        if (debug) fprintf(stderr, "parent exiting\n");
        else fprintf(stdout, "\n");

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: which string in this function? SHow us the calling code too

Comment: As you are declaring them the strings are local to **string_breakdown()** function, you would need to return either __*delim__ or __*sep__ depending on what main() needs, and change the return type of this function  to __char *__

Comment: @pm100 I added the function call code

Comment: @ArifBurhan those two weren't needed, which is why they were local

Comment: `output_str = realloc (output_str,...` :  never update `output_str` in caller-side.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY could you elaborate on that and tell me why? I did it assuming it was okay. If its not would you tell me what was wrong and how to implement it correctly?

Comment: @pm100 The string which lose values are `filename`, `output_str` and `command`.

Comment: Because pass by value in C. (filename ditto)

Comment: @BLUEPIXY is this not contradictory to what pm100 is saying, who takes the stance that things should be realloc'd but differently?

Comment: [simple sample code](http://ideone.com/heQtzD)

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I've tried your implementing your sample code in mine and I get segmentation faults earlier than before, despite seeing how your code is functionally the same as you're dereferencing a *** to ** which is what I was doing to begin with. With the code as above output_str is getting a segmentation fault upon exiting the function while filename is exiting safely. Have you any ideas why this may be or why I get errors sooner with your implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
        output_str = realloc (output_str, (count + 1) * sizeof (char *) );
```

This line re-assigns the value of the the local parameter variable `output_str`, but the new value in no way makes it back to the caller of the `string_breakdown` function - meaning that the pointer it *has* will probably be left dangling, and will cause problems when used ("undefined behavior", manifesting in strange program behavior or crashing).

You need to understand that within the function, `output_str` is a local variable. You can change its value, but that won't affect the value of any variable in the caller.

You call the function from `main`:

```
             string_breakdown(line, output_str, count, temp, filename, &f, &saved_stdout, flag, debug); // The call of the above function
```

`main` also uses `output_str` as the variable name, but again, this is a *different* variable. One variable is local to `main`, the other is local to `string_breakdown`, even though they share the same name. Due to the `realloc` call above, the pointer value in `main`'s `output_str` will most likely be invalid on return from `string_breakdown`, because it is not updated to point to the newly allocated memory. **That's why you are "losing" the string values on return from the function** - the `output_str` variable in `main` is no longer actually pointing to the array of strings, which has been moved to a different location via `realloc`.

Typically you resolve this kind of problem by adding another level of indirection, changing the `output_str` parameter from a `char **` to a `char ***`:

```
void string_breakdown(char *line, char ***output_str, int count, char* temp, char *filename, int *f, int *saved_stdout, int flag, int debug)
```

and

```
       (*output_str)[count] = temp;
```

and

```
       *output_str = realloc (*output_str, (count + 1) * sizeof (char *) );
```

and so on. You need to adjust the call in `main` as well:

```
             string_breakdown(line, &output_str, count, temp, filename, &f, &saved_stdout, flag, debug); // The call of the above function
```

Because you are passing a *pointer* to `main`'s `output_str` variable, the called function is now able to modify its value.

You should also understand that `string_breakdown` as written modifies the string which the `line` parameter points to. That's because it uses `strtok`, and `strtok` replaces delimiters with nul bytes as it processes the string. So, it is odd that you pass this modified line buffer to `com_exec` after processing it with `string_breakdown`.

I get several warnings when I try to compile your code; `main.c` uses `fprintf` but doesn't `#include <stdio.h>`, and uses `malloc` but doesn't `#include <stdlib.h>`.

Comment: I edited the code above to reflect your suggestion but where it would only cause segmentation faults if `flag = 1` before now all processes produce segmentation faults. I added the extra dereferencing `*`'s and passed the address. I'm not sure if my edit is visible. Can you see if it matches what you said as my code is currently less functional.

Comment: @BitFlow you should not now edit the question to match this answer since that means you are now asking a _different_ question and this answer no longer applies to it. I am confident my changes here are improvements, if you still get segfaults it may be that you have other problems in your code. You should try to understand my answer or ask questions until you do, then ask a second question to resolve further problems (after trying to debug yourself first of course).

Comment: @BitFlow BTW it would be much easier to help if you provide a [mcve]. I can't compile and test the code you've posted because it is not complete.

Comment: I'm sorry, I was unaware of how I wasn't obeying rules. I was trying to help, I'm sorry. I can revert the edit of course. Sorry for the incomplete nature, I was trying to be minimal as the code has a main file, a functions file and a header file. Would I simply add the entire files to the code snippets above or share another way?

Comment: @BitFlow you don't need to be sorry :) If your code is not too large you can post it all in the question, but ideally you should try to remove any unnecessary functionality (as long as you still see the problem). Read the MCVE link I posted in the comment above for guidance. You should provide sample input that you use to cause the crash.

Comment: @BitFlow   Ok, there was an error in one of my suggested changes. `*output_str[count] = temp;` should have been `(*output_str)[count] = temp;`. Seems to work better now.

Comment: The brackets definitely fixed it. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

your realloc does nothing.

you mean `*output_ptr = realloc....`

actually it does something, but its really bad

this is also wrong

```
output_str[count] = temp;
```

and this

```
filename = output_str[1];
```

you need to distinguish - a pointer to your buffer, a pointer to the pointer to your buffer.

```
  char * buffer = *output_str; // to remove the confusion
  strcpy(&buffer[count], temp); // assigning pointers doesnt copy things


filename = buffer[1]; // is hat what you mean - filename is one char
```

Comment: Can I ask how does *output_str differ?

Comment: *output_ptr= says - store this pointer where output_ptr points. output_ptr = says overwrite this pointer. Go read up on pointers and indirection

Comment: I implemented the `*output_str = realloc...` change and things actually got worse, now commands are all unrecognised

Comment: thats cos you have other errors too - read up on pointers etc. See updates answer

Comment: When you say I have other errors, are these errors that you can see? If so what do you see?

Comment: Since output_str is ** output_str[1] is actually a whole string, not a character.

Yes `=` assigns memory not a value but strtok isn't strcpy, it is breaking down the string, not copying it when dealing with temp